# What is the state of the art process for finding isolated communities in graphs?

Tags: graph-theory, igraph

Is there a state of the art process to follow for finding [isolated communities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Community_structure) in graphs?

I know there are a lot of algorithms available, but I struggle to find a set of steps for preprocessing and to provide clues as to which algorithm should be used/ is most suitable to each graph at hand.

Answer (score 2):

My feeling is that the Louvain method is a classical way to detect communities.
It's a bit old be you can find in the paper of [Lancichinetti and Fortunato](https://arxiv.org/abs/0908.1062) (2009) some comparisons.

If your networks are not too large, a simple modularity optimization should works (using a simulated annealing for example).

I guess that the answer will also depends on the size of graphs

Comment: Thanks for the reference, I was mainly looking for methods that could be applicable to large graphs, where by large I mean 1000 to 10000 nodes.